# How to convert multiple rows to one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usage` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `state` enum('LinuxTU','LinuxExt','View','Browser','Idle','Offline') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Offline',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `host_id` (`host_id`),
  KEY `time_id` (`time_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12998 ;
```

This table stores state infos for different computers.

I actually can get this. Which stores the values I need but not in correct format:

```
SELECT time_id, state, COUNT(state) statecount
FROM `usage` u
GROUP BY time_id, state
```

Result:

```
time_id  state      statecount
      7  LinuxTU            20
      7  LinuxExt           11
      7  View               51
      7  Browser             5
      7  Idle               67
      7  Offline            83
      8  LinuxTU            22
      8  LinuxExt           10
      8  View               55
      8  Browser             4
      8  Idle               66
      8  Offline            80
```

I want to get a matrix with counted state values out of it like this:

```
time_id   LinuxTU   LinuxExt   View   Browser   Idle   Offline
      7        20         11     51         5     67        83
      8        22         10     55         4     66        80
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Do you know the six additional columns that you want?  Or do these depend on the data?  If the first, google "mysql pivot".  If the second, google "mysql dynamic pivot".

Comment: There's already a stackoverflow question for pivoting data, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

OK, pivot table is the key. Perhaps there is a query wihtout subquerys but I didn't find it. And this query is not flexible to column changes.
But it works...

```
SELECT time_id,
    SUM(IF(state='LinuxTU', statecount, NULL)) AS LinuxTU,
    SUM(IF(state='LinuxExt', statecount, NULL)) AS LinuxExt,
    SUM(IF(state='View', statecount, NULL)) AS View,
    SUM(IF(state='Browser', statecount, NULL)) AS Browser,
    SUM(IF(state='Idle', statecount, NULL)) AS Idle,
    SUM(IF(state='Offline', statecount, NULL)) AS Offline
FROM (
    SELECT time_id, state, COUNT(state) statecount
    FROM `usage` u
    GROUP BY time_id, state
) AS subtab
GROUP BY time_id
```